# Two different subscriptions in ngOnInit return undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having two subscriptions in my ngOnInit(), I'm using the result of the first sub in the second one like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.Context.state$.subscribe((site) => {
      this._siteId = site.id;
    });

    this.SummaryContext.state$.subscribe((summary) => {
      this._unityId = this.siteSummaryContext.getFromId(summary, this._siteId).unityId;
    });
```

}

the _siteId variable is declared globaly, but I can't use in the getFromId() method, it's undefined.
what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Observables are asynchronous. When the state of `SummaryContext` is subscribed, the `_siteId` might be still not set.

You can combine those `Observables` together to make sure the `_siteId` is always available:

```js
this.Context.state$
  .pipe(
     switchMap(site => {
         this._siteId = site.id;
         return this.SummaryContext.state$;
     })
  )
  .subscribe((summary) => {
      this._unityId = this.siteSummaryContext.getFromId(summary, this._siteId).unityId;
  });
```

You can change the order if needed.